# Function object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function funcObj() { } 
funcObj.prototype.greet = "hello";
console.log(funcObj.greet) // undefined ???
console.log(funcObj.prototype.greet) // hello

var obj = new funcObj();
console.log(obj.greet); // hello
```

As per my understanding in prototype. If you access a member of an object it will get it from prototype object when not available in that object.

My questions is:

since functions in Javascript are objects why `funcObj.greet` -> undefined, but `obj.greet` -> hello?

Comment: Only constructor functions have a `.prototype` property, which is used when you call them with `new`. All objects do have a *prototype*, but this is not a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prototype is nothing more than an object from which instances inherit properties.

So, `funcObj` is an instance of another prototype (the one of `Function`) from which it has inherited all the properties. Also, it has for itself a `prototype` on which you can bind whatever you want and that prototype will be used once you invoke it to construct new instances of `funcObj` (that is, when you invoke it along with the `new` keywork, as `new funcObj()`).

Because of that, it's perfectly normal that `funcObj` doesn't have a member called `greet`, while its instances have it.

Comment: hence every function object itself is an instance from Function constructor. so if i add my property to Function.prototype it will shared by all function instances , is right ?

Comment: More or less. Actually, the scope to which the function is bound differs, it is the current *this* reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function is *a different object* than the instance.

Putting a property on one object will not affect any other object; not even the function that that object or prototype is an instance of.

Answer (score 0):

Much like a `class Foo` is not itself the same type as a `new Foo`, there is no reason for `Foo` to have any properties you assign to `Foo.prototype`.  The reasons are a little different, but consider it in another language like java and it's apparent that what you're trying to do just should not work:

```
class Foo {
    public String bar = "analogous to Foo.prototype.bar which is a property of Foo instances";
}

class Baz {
    String thisMethodShouldAndWillFail() {
        return Foo.bar;
    }
    String thisIsWhatShouldAndWillWork() {
        return (new Foo()).bar;
    }
}
```

In javascript, you need to correct your idea of what a prototype is and how it is related to objects and constructors, or you will run into problems continually.  A `foo` has a prototype, but that prototype is *not* `foo.prototype`.  There is *no* property of `foo` itself that is its prototype.  The `foo`'s prototype is determined by its *constructor* `Foo`; it makes more sense this way because you could assign any old value to `foo.prototype` after it is constructed, which breaks `foo` by turning it into an instance of a class for which it was not initialized.

The constructor `Foo` would similarly not make any sense if it would act as an instance of the class it defines; it has not been initalized by itself, so it cannot safely be assumed that it will fulfill the behavior intended for its instances.  `Foo` is an instance of `Function`, which makes sense because it can be called.  Therefore the prototype *of* `Foo` is `Function.prototype`, *not* `Foo.prototype`.

The relationship between a `foo` and its prototype is set up when you call `foo = new Foo`.  Since the body of the constructor `Foo` is expected to initialize the instance, this is the *only* time to give `foo` its prototype that makes sense.  The prototype provides an object its common behaviors, the constructor initializes the object so that these behaviors will work as intended.  The prototype that is assigned to `foo` when it is constructed via `new Foo` is none other than `Foo.prototype`; this is done *before* `Foo` is executed for convenience and a guarantee that it cannot possibly be messed up.  Following that, there is no way to access the prototype of `foo` without going through `Foo` explicitly.

```
enter code here
```